# ActionScript3 interface implementation without public accessor?

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, syntax

In C#, it's possible implementing interface methods without making implementing method as `public`. For example,

```
void ITest.SomeMethod() 
{
    // ... 
}
```

Is there equivalent for ActionScript3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. From the [AS3 Language Spec](http://livedocs.adobe.com/specs/actionscript/3/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?href=as3_specification97.html):

> Classes that implement an interface method must use the public attribute to implement all interface methods.

Answer (score 1):

In ActionScript, there is no way to add access level qualifiers; however, this question has been asked here, leveraging inheritance of interfaces:

[How to expose a method in an interface without making it public to all classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691989/how-to-expose-a-method-in-an-interface-without-making-it-public-to-all-classes)

Perhaps an internal class may be another approach; although, not recommended.

But directly no, all members of ActionScript interfaces are public.